# Fridge stoped working properly

Tags: fluid-pump, compression

a Friend have a problem with the fridge&freezer - it does not produce coldness anymore.

Company : AEG Electrolux

Model :  S 75348KG5

Typ : CBFF340 EL

We would like to know why, and what we can do about it.

It is connected to the grid,
light and sensor indicators are on,
fan/ventilator(?) in freezer is working,
Compressor on the bottom back is vibrating,
No wet leakage are found - however on one pipe there is a bit rust.

Still the heat exchange grid, keep being cold,

later on i can provide some proper electrical sketch.

Thank you,

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There **may** be a defrost timer in the fridge. These are notorious for failing.

Comment: A fridge does not "produces cold" it moves heat from one place to another...

Comment: _"We would like to know why, and what we can do about it."_ - It's broken. Time to buy a new one!

Answer (score 1):

Refrigerant leak may be a probable cause of the problem. In that case refilling would be the solution.